# Find the numbers that repeat in a vector that contains numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the numbers that repeat in a vector that contains numbers from 1 to 100 in Java. If multiple numbers repeat, display them in ascending order. If no number is repeated, display 0.

Input: an integer> 0, an array inputVector [n].
Output: the array with numbers.

Code:

```java
/*
for N = 12 and A = {9,31,38,5,62,44,38,17,19,38,50,74}, the result is 38.
for N = 12 and A = {9,31,38,5,62,44,38,17,19,38,50,31}, the result is 31,38.
for N = 12 and A = {4,3,14,15,18,39,56,89,101,150,165,187}, the result is 0. 
This is my work.   
*/

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputVector = null;
        int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int n;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
            n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            String[] numberTokens = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            inputVector = new int[numberTokens.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberTokens.length; i++) {
                inputVector[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberTokens[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberTokens.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < numberTokens.length; j++) {
                if (numberTokens[i] = numberTokens[j]) result = numberTokens[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: This code won't compile, at least because of `if ( numberTokens[i]=numberTokens[j] )`. You presumably intend `==` rather than `=`.

Comment: @Gatusko how to solve this !

Comment: You should store result in a String.

Comment: @AndyTurner i fixed this but this is not the problem

Comment: What are the constraints? Because one simple solution is to put each number into a `Map<Integer,Integer>` where the key is the number in the `A` and the value is the number of times seen, and then filter. But if one cannot use a `Map`, or one is constrained to memory O(1), then that's out. Or sort the array and check for consecutive numbers. Unless one cannot sort...

Comment: Declare numberTokens outside try block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `HashSet` and a `Stream` to find the duplicates in your array:

```
int[] inputVector = new int[]{6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3};
Set<Integer> uniqueVector = new HashSet<>();
int[] duplicates = Arrays.stream(inputVector)
        .filter(i -> !uniqueVector.add(i))
        .sorted().toArray();

if (duplicates.length > 0) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(duplicates));
} else {
    System.out.println(0);
}
```

The result in this case would be `0`.

For the input array `{6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3, 6, 3, 9}` the result would be `[3, 6, 9]`.

Comment: @samuel_Philiip thanks :) 
can you please give me your mail to contact you